# Как запустить исполняемый файл на Android?

Tags: android, linux

Одно из десктопных приложений зависит от файла `plancoincli.exe`. Приложение вызывает этот файл с определенными аргументами, получает ответ в формате `json` и выводит данные в интерфейс.

Например, чтобы определить, есть ли соединение с сервером, в `plancoincli.exe` отправляется команда `status`

В **Windows** мне достаточно разместить `plancoincli.exe` в директории с главным файлом GUI-приложения и вызвать системную команду

```
plancoincli.exe status
```

или

```
plancoincli status
```

После чего прочитать ответ от программы ы вывести данные.

---

Теперь нужно сделать такое же приложение под андроид. Прежде, чем делать что-то в Android Studio, я решил поработать с файлом вручную. Однако здесь возникли трудности.

У меня есть файл `plancoincli` в директории `storage/emulated/0/Python/PlanTest/`, однако при его вызове я получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я также пробовал запускать так:

```
./plancoincli
```

Но при этом получаю такую ошибку:

```
sh: ./plancoincli: Exec format error
```

---

**В чем моя ошибка и как это можно запустить на Android?**

[**Здесь можно скачать `plancoincli`**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ip_QmL_vuwuQon_ND_-cuLPMqElLy9M5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Очевидно, этот файл совершенно не предназначен для запуска на андроиде

Comment: Это не тот же самый файл, что и для windows. Файл для винды был скомпилирован на windows, а этот на линуксе

Comment: Но при этом для андроида его никто не компилировал, и запустить его на андроиде нельзя

Comment: то есть достаточно его скомпилировать на андроиде и ошибка должна уйти?

Comment: @andreymal но ведь андроид по сути и есть линукс, так как работает его ядре? Почему файл для линукса не совместим?

Comment: Потому что, для начала, посмотрите на архитектуру скомпилированного файла - он для процессоров x86-64, а на большинстве андроид-устройств стоит arm (обычно aarch64). Затем, этот файл динамически линкуется с библиотеками libc.so.6 и libpthread.so.0, которых на андроиде отродясь не было

Comment: @andreymal так или иначе, порядок действий у меня правильный? Если будет нормальный файл, то все получится? Или я как-то неправильно обращаюсь к файлу?